# C/C++, strlen(NULL)

Tags: c, null, strlen

Почему эта функция не проверяет переданный ей аргумент на **NULL**?

Самое интересное, что мало где пишут, что **strlen(NULL)** приводит к сегфолту. Даже в книжке С.Прата за 2015 год нет ни слова о том, что функция не выполняет названную проверку. Очень странно.

Comment: а почему она должна проверять на null? null указатель не является строкой ни в каком смысле.

Comment: Да чем вам так понравился тег `cc++`? :) Те, кто интересуются С/С++ ищут вопросы по тегам С и C++. А ваш новый тег ни у кого в избранном не забит.

Comment: [*"Следует отдавать предпочтение уже существующим меткам, а новые создавать только тогда, когда у вас есть веские причины считать, что вопрос затрагивает тему, которая не обсуждалась ранее."*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat При написании в поле для ввода меток "с/с++"  оно сворачивается сайтом в [cc++], видимо поэтому так и получается

Answer (score 13, accepted):

На самом деле ничего странного в этом нет. Средства стандартных библиотек C и C++ часто не используют дополнительных проверок корректности аргументов в угоду эффективности. Многие средства уже предполагают, что программист сделал проверку, либо она вовсе не нужна, т.к. есть какая-то гарантия валидности аргумента. Если же сделать проверку внутри функций, то получим потерю производительности из-за лишних проверок. Возьмем простой пример:

```
if (str) {//Проверка на ноль
    size = strlen(str);//А внутри strlen была бы еще одна проверка
} else {
    printf("error\n");
}
```

Тоже самое можно отнести, например, к `std::vector::operator[]`:

```
for(size_type i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) { //Мы не выйдем за пределы вектора
    vec[i] = i;//Но в operator[] всё равно была бы еще одна проверка
}
```

И если с вектором всё более менее понятно - есть отдельная функция-член `at`, проверяющая валидности индекса, то с `strlen` чуть сложнее. Что должна вернуть эта функция, если ей передали `NULL`? Нужна была бы какая-то константа для определения факта ошибки и опять же, дополнительные проверки.

К слову о том, что об этом нигде не пишут. На самом деле - пишут. 
Например, на cppreference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen

> **Parameters** 
> str    -   pointer to the null-terminated byte string to be
>   examined

Аргументом strlen должен быть указатель на `null-terminated byte string`, коим `NULL` не является.

Но можно обратиться и к стандарту C. Для `strlen` никаких требования не указано, поэтому согласно

> Вырезка из документа N1570 
>   **7.24.1 String function conventions** 
>  ... 
>  Unless explicitly stated otherwise in the description of a particular function in this subclause, pointer arguments on such a call shall still have valid values, as described in 7.1.4.

аргумент должен иметь валидное значение, согласно описанному в `7.1.4`:

> **7.1.4  Use of library functions**
>   **Each of the following statements applies unless explicitly stated otherwise in the detailed descriptions that follow**: **If an argument to a function has an invalid value** (**such as** a value outside the domain of the function, or a pointer outside the address space of the program, **or a null pointer**, or a pointer to non-modifiable storage when the corresponding parameter is not const-qualified) or a type
>   (after promotion) not expected by a function with variable number of
>   arguments, **the behavior is undefined**

а согласно этому пункту, как видим, передача нулевого указателя приводит к неопределенному поведению.

Comment: [Средства стандартных библиотек C и C++ часто не используют дополнительных проверок корректности аргументов в угоду эффективности.] Золотые слова. Много можно чего проверять в разных функциях вместо того чтобы делать свою работу. Если программисту чего-то надо проверить, то он всегда может все проверить снаружи функции. А если делать проверку внутри функции, то ее оттуда уже не вытащишь и эффективность пострадает.

Comment: Но в operator[] есть проверка в дебаге

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков это не более чем хотелки разработчиков компилятора и только в целях отладки.

Comment: @Croessmah однако это не отменяет того, что эти хотелки есть в 3 компиляторах С++, а большинство вещей из С++ стд(и других С++ либ) ведёт себя довольно безопасно и не накручивает сегфолтов. В отличие от С либ.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков еще раз - передача неправильного индекса в operator[] - неопределенное поведение. Стандарт не дает никаких гарантий. Всё остальное - хотелки, крутилки, вертелки, случай и т.д. Никакого отношения к языку C++ это уже не имеет. И даже эти компиляторы, скорее всего, выпиливают все проверки из релизной версии. Так а что там стандарт говорит о отладочных версиях? Правильно - ничего.